# How to properly extend a styled component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

As per styled-components v4, `.extend` is deprecated, the correct way to extend, or compose components is:

```
const ButtonA = styled('button')`color: ${props => props.color};`
const ButtonB = styled(ButtonA)`background: 'white';`
```

However I can't find the correct way to do this with TS, as I get some errors, for example:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

// Let's create ButtonA
type ButtonAProps = { a: string };
const ButtonA = styled<ButtonAProps, "button">("button")`
  color: ${props => props.a};
`;

// So, here is what I've tried

// Fail #1
// =======
type ButtonBProps = { b: string };
const ButtonB = styled<ButtonBProps, ButtonAProps>(ButtonA)`
  background: ${props => props.b};
`; // Here I get autocompletion only for B props :(
const Test = () => <ButtonB a="something" />; // And here I get autocompletion only for A props :(

// Fail #2
// =======
type ButtonBProps = { b: string } & ButtonAProps;
const ButtonB = styled<ButtonBProps, ButtonAProps>(ButtonA)`
  background: ${props => props.b};
`; //  Here I get autocompletion for A & B props, good!
const Test = () => <ButtonB a="something" />; // Here I still get autocompletion only for A props :(

// Fail #3
// =======
type ButtonBProps = { b: string } & ButtonAProps;
const ButtonB = styled<ButtonBProps, ButtonBProps>(ButtonA)` // Property 'b' is missing in type 'ButtonAProps', of course
  background: ${props => props.b};
`; //  Here I get "props has implicitly any type"
const Test = () => <ButtonB />; // Here I don't get any type checking at all
```

Seems to be almost there, but can't figure it out.

Any advices? Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of September 2019, the following code also works:

```
// First extend ButtonAProps with an additional prop
interface ButtonBProps extends ButtonAProps {
  b:string;
}

// ButtonB Component
const ButtonB = styled(ButtonA)<ButtonBProps>`
  background: ${props => props.b};
`;
```

Comment: extends here is optional, styled-components is smart enough to infer parent type; a simple `styled(ButtonA)<{b: string}>` will work too and u will still extend ButtonProps

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work for me:

```
type ButtonBProps = { b: string };
const ButtonB = styled<ButtonAProps>(ButtonA)<ButtonBProps>`
  background: ${props => props.b};
`;
const Test = () => <ButtonB a="something" b="somethingelse" />;
```

The `@types/styled-components` declarations are hard to understand (with unhelpful type parameter names `P`, `T`, `O`, `U`) and apparently undocumented, so I can't be sure this is the intended approach.  I found [a related issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630), but it doesn't seem to confirm this approach.

Comment: Thank you, certainly does the job! Would be nice to have a cleaner approach though, just like union type or extending from the main interface.

Comment: Actually, with latest typescript you can just do `styled(A)<B>`

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't need parent type, just as others have mentioned styled(A)<B>

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2021, @Zalaboza's answer in the comments helped me most and is the simplest implementation.

Styled-components is smart enough to infer parent type:

```
styled(ButtonA)<{b: string}>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get: `An instantiation expression cannot be followed by a property access.ts(1477)`